# passing data from fragment to activity is not same

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment

I have fragment in activity. and I want to send data from fragment to activity.
[image]

how I get data in Fragment and send to my Activity:

```
val edit = question!!.id
(activity as QuestionActivity).kirimItem(edit)
```

in activity :

```
fun kirimItem(item: String) {
    idItem = item
}
```

and I call idItem in the button next onClick and show Toast the value from idItem

in the fragment, when I test data, question!!.id = 8
but toast is showing 11. The question is, why passing data from fragment to activity is not same. please guide me:(

Comment: This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241857/kotlin-pass-data-between-fragment-from-it-main-activity-is-null

Comment: Breakpoint `idItem = item` see if that's called more than it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that what is the rest of our code. This piece of code below works for me.

```
// Fragment, `btn` is Button and `edt` is EditText
btn.setOnClickListener {
    (activity as MainActivity?)?.callToast(edt.text.toString())
}

// Activity
fun callToast(str: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, str, LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: I try this code, but the toast is a show 8, 10, 11. it shows one by one. and i don't know why

Comment: Could you show more information about your piece of code? Like
1. make sure that the rest of your code does NOT touch your variable `idItem`
2. If some pieces of code relate `idItem` variable, you need to show all of them, especially for other setting value on that variable.
3. If possible, show entire code of both activity and fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are recommendations for passing data between activities and fragments (in a same activity). These are possible scenarios.

1. (Activity -> Activity)
2. (Activity -> Fragment)
3. (Fragment -> Activity)
4. (Fragment -> Fragment)

For 1., just use just use `android.content.Intent`. For 2., 3. and 4. scenarios, we can use `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel` to passing data between them. An example for `4. (Fragment -> Fragment)` is here (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) under topic `Share data between fragments`.

For that example, it can be applied not only `4.` scenario but also to `2.` and `3.` as well.

Comment: This is good practice, but it does not tell what was the issue.

Comment: Sry for not telling that root cause. After a moment, it works for me. Plz see it in next answer.